# Laravel View Cache keeps interrupting

Tags: laravel, caching, view

I'm doing my thing in my normal view blade file, but when i edit my code and save it, it doesn't update. I found out that the view cache stored in /storage/framework/views keeps interrupting. Whatever i change in my normal blade file doesn't change the output. It only reacts to my cache, which doesn't update. I've already cleared my cache, but it doesn't work, it keeps coming back. Is there any way i can ignore or delete the view cache?

Comment: Did you try php artisan view:clear?

Comment: "I've already cleared my cache, but it doesn't work" Yes , i did.

Comment: does it delete the files from the storage folder?

Comment: because there might be a permission issue.

Comment: If you have error in php artisan route:list, view:clear will not work too. Please Check your routes too. Maybe there is a problem with routes.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! The issue is gone now. Somehow i had 2 of the same blade files and i edited the wrong one, which is really weird. I don't know how i had 2 of the same blade files. I deleted one and now it works fine. Really weird though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help! The issue is gone now. Somehow i had 2 of the same blade files and i edited the wrong one, which is really weird. I don't know how i had 2 of the same blade files. I deleted one and now it works fine. Really weird though.

Answer (score 0):

```
   php artisan clear
   php artisan route:clear
   php artisan cache:clear
```

Run the above codes in your terminal it should do the trick, if it persists try reloading your editor.

Answer (score -1):

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Try this.